# Android Shape Bug on Which Android Version

Tags: android, shapes, android-drawable

I have created a set of shapes which work perfectly on Android 4.4:
[image]
However, when I tested it on 2.3:
[image]
The bottom corners are switched, and it is condensed (which is probably a height problem).
So I decided to create a folder like `drawable-v14` and assign different shapes for different versions, but I need to know which Android versions have there bugs. I could not test it on all versions!

**EDIT**
The shape for Button number 7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/rounded_stroke_color" />

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/rounded_radius_default"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="@dimen/rounded_stroke_normal_half"
        android:bottom="@dimen/rounded_stroke_normal"
        android:left="@dimen/rounded_stroke_normal"
        android:right="@dimen/rounded_stroke_normal_half">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/rounded_fill_color" />

            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/rounded_radius_default"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />

            <padding
                android:left="@dimen/rounded_padding_left"
                android:right="@dimen/rounded_padding_right" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

BTW the values are stored in a different resource file.

Comment: I've never hear about bug like this in android. Can you post your drawables and layout file. I think you missing something. I think you have missed padding (which may be defined in default style in android 4.4, but not defined in android 2.3). What about other problem, I need to see drawables and layout file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, let's start with your code.
First of all, you don't need to have layer-list for that. You can do it like this:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/rounded_stroke_color" />
            <stroke android:color="@color/comments_dark_color" android:width="@dimen/stroke_width"/>
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/rounded_radius_default"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />

        </shape>
```

ABout problem with corners, you are right. It is known bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9161. This bug was fixed in android 3.1

As @DerGolem says, there is hack:

> Lucky us, there is a workaround: the workaround is to put the
>   "correct" drawbles in the drawable-v12 folder, and the reversed ones
>   in the drawable folder

Comment: Lucky us, there is a workaround: `the workaround is to put the "correct" drawbles in the drawable-v12 folder, and the reversed ones in the drawable folder`

Comment: @DerGolem yes, you are right. This hack is posted on the link too.

Comment: Yes, it's where I took it from, just put it here for commodity.

Comment: The reason I use layer-list is because I am using different strokes for different size (as you can see)

Comment: If it was fixed in 3.0, then shouldn't it be a drawable-v11?

Comment: @jyoon sorry, I have mistake. Bug was fixed in android 3.1 (you need to use drawable-v12)